# Как использовать новые HTML5 теги при разработке Single Page Application?

Tags: html5, spa

Есть ли смысл использовать новые теги при создании веб-приложения?

Если да - то приведите, пожалуйста, пример. Hапример, на основе приложения - текстового редактора и тегов: `article`, `aside`, `footer`, `header`, `nav`.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 никак не влияет на функциональность SPA. Естественно семантика важна всегда. Тем более со всей мощью HTML5. Смело используйте любые теги, более того - я советую это делать. Это поднимет вас в глазах поисковиков. :)

P.S. Где и когда использовать новые теги советую почитать тут http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/verstka-na-html5/novye-tegi ибо всё сюда не перепишешь. :)

Comment: Да, но как я понимаю семантичный веб создан в первую очередь для поисковиков и браузеров с поддержкой режима для людей с ограниченными возможностями, таким образом оправданием для использования этих тегов являются либо необходимость индексации содержимого (а индексировать там нечего, не пункты же меню) и для экранных дикторов он не нужен.

Comment: Всё верно понимаете. Если вам индексация не важна, то и загоняться смысла нет. P.S. Даже меню поисковик разбирает как "меню", если там тег **nav**. :)